# Using XDebug for Drupal 6.14 on Snow Leopard?

Tags: php, drupal, osx-snow-leopard, xdebug

Just wondering if you anybody has had much luck getting XDebug working for Drupal 6.14 on Snow Leopard?

I noticed that Snow Leopard seems to come with php 5.3 which some people say *should* work with Drupal 6.14, though I haven't had any luck.

After that failed, I tried installing php 5.2 using macports (checking out from CVS at a previous revision number).  This works fine for php.  However, I have had no such luck getting XDebug going.

Any thoughts???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If xdebug is enabled it should show up if you execute a phpinfo();.    After xdebug is configured properly you can connect to it using Netbeans.  Download the php version here: [NetBeans Download](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).  You will have to create a project and point netbeans to your Drupal install.  After that you can set breakpoints and press run.

Comment: I actually have XDebug working on a non Snow-Leopard machine so I know how to set it up.  I can also get XDebug working with php 5.3, just not with 5.2.

Comment: sweet,  NetBeans can connect to remote xdebug installs.

Answer (score 0):

I created a step by step instruction on how to install and enable Xdebug with Netbeans:
http://lucwollants.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/xdebug-and-snow-leopard-more-cake/

Hope this can also help!